# Magento 2 Is it good idea to use ES6 syntax in custom modules?

Tags: magento2, javascript

Some developers suggest avoiding ES6 syntax in JS files to keep the entire codebase unified with a single JS standard.

After examining the vendor folder I saw some modules use es6 `For example vendor/vertexinc/module-tax/view/base/web/js/form/element/custom-option-flex-field-select.js`.

So, that's why I have doubts about the statement about avoiding using es6 syntax.